# Como criar um projeto com JSF, Primefaces e Tomcat que rode no Eclipse e Netbeans ao mesmo tempo?

Tags: java, eclipse, jsf, java-ee, netbeans

Como posso criar um projeto Maven com JSF, Primefaces e Apache Tomcat de forma que este rode tanto no Eclipse quanto no Netbeans sem problemas? (De preferência com as últimas versões das tecnologias)?

Comment: Não sei se é o melhor jeito, mas consegui criando o projeto no eclipse, fiz algumas configurações básicas no project facets, depois importei pelo netbeans passando o workspace do eclipse e depois pegando o projeto. Adicionei o primefaces pelo netbeans e o eclipse respondeu corretamente depois. Aparentemente funcional.

Comment: curiosidade: porque você pretende usar dois ambientes de desenvolvimento ao mesmo tempo? a princípio, não parece ser uma boa idéia =D

Comment: @MarceloBezerra, vi na prática que as IDEs tem vantagens e desvantagens distintas uma da outra. Hora é melhor usar uma, hora outra. Também, isso me permitiria usar a IDE padrão do trabalho, por exemplo, e fazer algumas outras coisas na outra, quando eu precisasse.

Answer (score 4):

Crie o seu projeto utilizando o Maven.

Tanto o Eclipse como o Netbeans respeitam o formato do Maven e desse modo você conseguirá ter os dois ambientes.

Esse projeto aqui não utilizar o JSF, mas é feito com Maven : http://uaihebert.com/aplicacao-web-completa-angular-twitter-bootstrap-spring-mvc-data-e-security/

Baixe o código fonte e mande importar tanto no Eclipse como no Netbeans, que ambos conseguirão entender o projeto.

Apenas tenha o cuidado, ao utilizar um versionador tipo SVN ou GIT, de não salvar os arquivos específicos de cada IDE, como o arquivo .project que o eclipse cria. Eles não são necessários para o funcionamento do projeto.

Outro detalhe é que para o Maven rodar corretamente no eclipse é necessário instalar um plugin. Nesse mesmo post mostra como configurar o Maven com o Eclipse.

Comment: Vou dar uma olhada no seu link e depois retorno. Mas uma coisa que você disse não é exatamente verdade, criar um maven no netbeans, por exemplo, não faz ele importável no eclipse. Tentei isso ontem, provavelmente porque o eclipse não tinha suporte a tomcat 8. Mas consegui fazendo o inverso, criando no eclipse e importando no netbeans.

Comment: Note que eu não disse sobre criar um projeto pela IDE. Pode ser que a IDE adicione seus próprios arquivos. Estude pelo menos o básico do maven para que você possa saber o que ele realmente necessita, uma vez que você domine isso você vai saber o que o netbeans adicionou a mais no projeto.